# Why are beta-lactam antibiotics the most common drug allergens?

Tags: allergy, antibiotics, immunology

> β-Lactam antibiotics: the most common allergens among drugs.
>
> Allergic reactions caused by β-lactam antibiotics bind to their
> chemical structure. The source of haptens is an unstable β-lactam ring
> to which proteins bind to form penicilloyl epitopes (called “major
> determinant”) responsible for the allergy to penicillin.

doi: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4692812/

Why are beta-lactam antibiotics the most common drug allergens?

I was thinking that  it could be due to the fact that beta-lactam antibiotics as Penicillins & Cephalosporins, are used in relatively higher amounts (e.g. 500 - 1000mg)

Also, maybe the mode of administration should play a role: other drugs used in the same weight range are given only orally (Vs. antibiotics which are often given parenterally)??

Comment: Consider what antibiotics are derived from. Unlike drugs, most of which are small molecule compounds, antibiotics are usually derived from organic compounds produced by bacteria and fungi.

Comment: @CareyGregory With a source that would seem to be an excellent answer, not a point I've heard before but seems interesting.

Comment: To be honest, I have seen more allergies to NSAIDS than antibiotics. The majority of people allergic to penicillin are not, in fact, allergic to the drug (via challenge) and about 10% of kids getting amoxicillin develop a rash, which is **not** a true allergic reaction, it's a commonly recognized "amoxicillin rash" which does not involve antibodies to the antibiotic. There is (or was) also a prevalent misbelief that people who are allergic to penicillin have a pretty high incidence of cephalosporin allergy. If you take these things into account, NSAIDS may well be the most common drug allergy.

Comment: Doctors today are often encouraged to ignore reported (x)cillin allergies except anaphylaxis. I wasn't brave enough to ignore all (x)cillin allergies, but If it was *not* hives, erythema multiforme, anaphylaxis, or some other significant allergy manifestation, I gave the drug. I once had the exceedingly unpleasant experience of giving an IV cephalosporin to someone who reported an (unknown-type of) allergic response to penicillin, only to observe the patient go into anaphylactic shock (at least they had an IV in place!) I never forgot that, and was more cautious there as well.

Comment: @anongoodnurse All of the sources I found in a quick search ranked NSAIDs as #2 behind antibiotics.

Comment: @CareyGregory - That's why I explained why I believe true allergies to antibiotics is lower than those to NSAIDS. If you subtract the patient-reported allergic reactions (which are orders of magnitude higher than the reality when tested for), the NSAIDS probably are #1. I've given antibiotics that patients were supposedly allergic to without problems too many times. (That one time was the single exception.) Such "allergies" also result in unnecessary use of broader spectrum antibiotics (hence the encouragement to ignore.)

Comment: @CareyGregory -  "After formal allergy evaluation, including penicillin skin testing, 90% to 99% of patients with reported allergy can tolerate penicillins." https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1081120615003361  Note that the cillins and cephalosporins make up the bulk of "antibiotic allergies".

Comment: @anongoodnurse Sounds like you should be writing an answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I usually don't write answers unless some prior research is edited into the question. It's not a lot to ask. But I do try to help the OP with hints or redirection.

Comment: Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-show-any-research), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please edit your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Specifically, a good source supporting your assertion that antibiotics are the most common drug allergen would be helpful.

Comment: Alright, i added a source

Comment: On a cursory reading of your source, I didn't see the confirmation that antibiotics were the most allergy-inducing drug. Kindly point me to where it does, because it seems to decidedly avoid making that statement. If you do not invest your time in a meaningful edit as @CareyGregory suggested, why would I invest time by answering? I've already spent time on this question in comments.

Comment: @anongoodnurse The paper isn't what I'd call the highest quality, but the heading "β-Lactam antibiotics: the most common allergens among drugs" certainly seems to make the claim.

Comment: @IanCampbell - If you could find that in the body of the paper (not a heading which is not supported), I'd be grateful. They *do* state that β-Lactams are most common allergens among antibiotics, which I already stated in comments.